# mySQL SUM a previous grouped query

Tags: mysql, sum, subquery, grouping

I need to get an aggregated result per MODEL that Sums the total count of previously filtered items from a previous query:

```
SELECT model, ratio, if(count(model)>=3,3,count(model)) AS gearcount 
FROM zfgearinv 
WHERE allocated = 0 AND sold = 0 
GROUP BY model, ratio 
ORDER BY model
```

In this query I am only showing <=3 items and then I only want to show the SUM of those items PER MODEL:

```
MODEL     RATIO GEARCOUNT
ZF 220A   1.23  2
ZF 220A   1.53  3
ZF 220A   1.75  3
ZF 220A   2     1
ZF 220A   2.45  2
ZF 220V   1.5   3
ZF 220V   1.75  1
ZF 220V   2     3
ZF 220V   2.5   3
```

So my final out put should read:

```
MODEL     TOTAL
ZF 220A   11
ZF 220V   10
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

all you need to do is wrap that query with an outer query where you do the SUM of your gearcount

```
SELECT model as MODEL, SUM(gearcount) as TOTAL
FROM
(   SELECT model, ratio, if(count(model)>=3,3,count(model)) AS gearcount 
    FROM zfgearinv 
    WHERE allocated = 0 AND sold = 0 
    GROUP BY model, ratio
) t
GROUP BY model
ORDER BY model
```